# Does a VPN encrypt the entire packet being tunneled, including all headers?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, proxy, encryption

If I send my internet traffic through a VPN, are the packets that I send encrypted completely and encapsulated in a second packet (i.e. every byte in the original packet is encrypted and added to a new packet as data), including all the headers (TCP header, IP header, etc).  I'd assume the destination IP address would have to be encrypted to prevent someone viewing the traffic from being able to trivially determine the final destination IP, but are all the other components of the IP and TCP headers encrypted and encapsulated?

I'm interested because of the possibility of information leakage on "secure" encrypted connections (for example someone watching your VPN traffic being able to determine the destination port of the original packet).

Also do anonymizing proxy networks like Tor or I2P encrypt and encapsulate the entire original packet, or are there parts of the original packet that are sent unencrypted in the new "encrypted" packet?

Comment: @Ramhound I've found information that indicates that the entire packet is indeed encapsulated and encrypted, but I asked here to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenVPN the whole ethernet frame or ip packet (depending on tun or tap mode) is encrypted.

> The encrypted packet is formatted as follows:
>
> - HMAC(explicit IV, encrypted envelope)
> - Explicit IV
> - Encrypted Envelope
>
> The plaintext of the encrypted envelope is formatted as follows:
>
> - 64 bit sequence number
> - payload data, i.e. IP packet or Ethernet frame

[Source](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html)

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i'm rather new to the whole stackexchange ;)